# Multiple regression

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression

We have this question in our assignment, can someone help?

> 17. Using the Unite States sample of the 2000 program for international student assessment(PISA), the difference in population mean (English) reading score between those who do and do not speak English at home is estimated with standard error of 10. When controlling for socioeconomic status, the adjusted difference in population
>
> mean reading score is estimated as 49 with a standard error of 10.
>
> a) What does it mean to "control" or "adjust for" socioeconomic status?
>
> b) Under what circumstances does controlling for a variable x1 alter the estimated regression coefficient of another variable x2.
>
> c) In the context of this example, explain why the adjusted estimate differs from the unadjusted estimate, paying attention to the direction of the difference.
>
> d) What means adjustment in multivariate analyses

Well I understood so far that the socioeconomic status is a confounder that one should adjust for, because it might also be correlated to the reading sore.... is that right so far? Additionally: that the mean in the population is 49. The standard error is calculated for the population mean right? Moreover for c) I suppose that the difference will be greater without adjustment because speaking English at home depends upon other factors like being an immigrant and thus (maybe) having a lower socioeconomic status which is correlated with lower grades and a lower performance.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Well I understood so far that the socioeconomic status is a confounder that one should adjust for, because it might also be correlated to the reading sore.... is that right so far? Additionally: that the mean in the population  is 49. The standard error is calculated for the population mean right? Moreover for c) I suppose that the difference will be greater without adjustment because speaking English at home depends upon other factors like being an immigrant and thus (maybe) having a lower socioeconomic status which is correlated with lower grades and a lower performance.@gung

Comment: Please add the tag, read the wiki, & add that information to your question.

Comment: okay i have added the tag